# Problem in (if) statement of login button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was creating a login page with backendless and I am facing the following problem as below:

"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference"

I am facing problem whenever I click login button with email and password.
The error shows in the if statement of login button.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText etEmail, etPassword;
  Button btnLogin, btnRegister;
  TextView tvForget;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please enter all fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                showProgress(true);
                Backendless.UserService.login(email, password, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser response) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "You are Logged in Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
                        Login.this.finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error: "+ fault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        showProgress(false);
                    }
                }, true);
            }

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your EditText (both) with

`etEmail.setText("")`

so in the IF statement just check

`if (etEmail.getText().equals("") || etPass.getText().equals("")`

Secondly, don't use `toString()` method, they are already strings.

****OR****

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etEmail.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(etPass.getText()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to use a variable, property, or a method return value but it contains null - which means that there is no instance of a class in the variable.

And going through your error, it seems you have not created an instance of EditText.

I have fixed this error by adding

```java
etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);  
etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
```

in onCreate method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).